# Get ID of Administrators in Moodle via webservice

Tags: web-services, moodle

how can I find out the ID of the administrators via a web service in moodle?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an existing webservice for that, probably for security

For reference, the site admin ids are in a comma separated list in

```
SELECT value
FROM mdl_config
WHERE name = 'siteadmins'
```

And here's the developer documentation to create a web service in Moodle

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/external